# I can't understand why this won't work (specifying a range within an array / if statement)

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var guestList = ['Gabe', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']

var guestName = prompt('Hello, what is your name')

var range = guestList.slice(0, guestList.length)

if (guestList.includes(range)) {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName} and welcome to EVENT NAME`)


} else {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName}, you are not on the guest list`)
}
```

Comment: do you mean guestList.includes(guestName); ?

Comment: You never use `guestName` in the `if` condition, so what do you expect to happen there?

Comment: Did you just mean `guestList.includes(guestName)`, but then I'm not sure why you created `range`..

Comment: Your question is not clear what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Remove `range` because it's useless and replace `range` in this line with `guestName`

```
if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {....
```

`Prompt()` returns a value which is whatever the user entered.

```js
var guestList = ['Gabe', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']

var guestName = prompt('Hello, what is your name')

/* Add this line if you want the comparison
to be case insensitive 
*/
// guestList = guestList.map(name => name.toLowerCase());

/* And replace guestName with
guestName.toLowerCase() in the "if"
statement as well.
*/
if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
  alert(`Hello ${guestName} and welcome to EVENT NAME`)
} else {
  alert(`Hello ${guestName}, you are not on the guest list`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
var guestList = ['Gabe', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']

var guestName = prompt('Hello, what is your name')

if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName} and welcome to EVENT NAME`)
} else {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName}, you are not on the guest list`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this works fine:

```js
var guestList = ['Gabe', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']

var guestName = prompt('Hello, what is your name')

if (guestList.includes(guestName)) { alert("Hello"+ guestName +"and welcome to EVENT NAME")

} else { alert("Hello "+ guestName+", you are not on the guest list") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on that line of your code `var range = guestList.slice(0, guestList.length)`. Now `range` is a **sub-array** of `guestList` and you´re trying to verifacate in `guestList`if it includes the **element** `range` that is not true.

I think you´re trying to do this:

```js
var guestList = ['Gabe', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']

var guestName = prompt('Hello, what is your name')

if (guestList.includes(guestName)) {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName} and welcome to EVENT NAME`)


} else {
    alert(`Hello ${guestName}, you are not on the guest list`)
}
```